# BinaryReader reading different length of data depending on BufferSize

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, binaryreader

The issue is as follows, I am using an `HttpWebRequest` to request some online data from  [dmo.gov.uk](http://www.dmo.gov.uk/xmlData.aspx?rptCode=D3B.2). The response I am reading using a `BinaryReader` and writing to a `MemoryStream`. I have packaged the code being used into a simple test method:

```
public static byte[] Test(int bufferSize)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.dmo.gov.uk/xmlData.aspx?rptCode=D3B.2");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

My real-life code uses a buffer size of 2048 bytes usually, however I noticed today that this file has a huge amount of empty bytes (`\0`) at the end which bloats the file size. As a test I tried increasing the buffer size to near-on the file size I expected (I was expecting ~80Kb so made the buffer size 79000) and now I get the right file size. But I'm confused, I expected to get the same file size regardless of the buffer size used to read the data.

The following test:

```
Console.WriteLine(Test(2048).Length);
Console.WriteLine(Test(79000).Length);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Yields the follwoing output:

```
131072
81341
```

The second figure, using the high buffer size is the exact file size I was expecting (This file changes daily, so expect that size to differ after today's date). The first figure contains `\0` for everything after the file size expected.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `ms.GetBuffer();` to `ms.ToArray();`.

`GetBuffer` will return the entire `MemoryStream` buffer while `ToArray` will return all the values inside the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Thank you. I've run into this exact issue before but could not for the life of me think what was going on.